# MVC default route with id not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to link to a controller with actually specifying the action parameter. I'm pretty sure this is possible. And got the concept from here:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs

These are the two links:

```
https://localhost/mvcapplication1/customer/order/index/6463 (WORKS)
https://localhost/mvcapplication1/customer/order/6463 (WANT THIS)
```

I specified a special rout for this controller (Customer_orders).

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Customer_orders",
        "Customer/Order/{orderId}",
        new { controller = "MvcApplication1.Areas.Customer.Controllers.Order", action = "Index" },
        new[] { "MvcApplication1.Areas.Customer.Controllers" }  // only map routes to controllers in the specified namespace
     );

    context.MapRoute(
        "Customer_default",
        "Customer/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new[] { "MvcApplication1.Areas.Customer.Controllers" }  // only map routes to controllers in the specified namespace
        );
}
```

And this is my controller with the namespace:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Areas.Customer.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public partial class OrderController : SupertextController
    {
```

I've also enabled the Route Debugger and according to that my routes are ok. So why do I get a "The resource cannot be found."? Specially since it works if I add "index" to the URL.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes the default value of the `controller` token should be your controller name without any namespace and without the `"Controller"` postfix:

So change your route to:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Customer_orders",
    "Customer/Order/{orderId}",
        new { controller = "Order", action = "Index" },
        new[] { "MvcApplication1.Areas.Customer.Controllers" }  
);
```

Comment: Silly me, had that indeed cause I had a conflict before.